# how do i change data by custom key in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an app which writes in firebase and I want my another app with admin privileges to read and edit the data present in the custom key
[image: *.*]

If this is the picture assume where a random key a my key and I want to edit the data or add new data with the present data in that particular custom key.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: So basically you want to update data only within those highlighted keys? Have you stored those keys somehow?

Comment: Along those same lines - how do you know which node you want to edit? e.g. how does the admin user select the data they want to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you want to get all the children, do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yourTable");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // All your data is in dataSnapshot
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    }
);
```

If you want to set a specific child's value by the key do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yourTable");
ref.child("mySpecificChildId").child("message").setValue("new value");
```

If these don't help, please add a more specific question!

Answer (score 0):

If these keys are auto generated and you cannot get a hold of them, it does not matter what privligies you have you cannot get them.

However, if you do have the key, or getting it from a function, and you want to change the values at the specific node or just read them you can just query the database for that key and change it after wards something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference().child("YOUR KEY");
```

and then you can access read and edit the values at the node

```
mRef.child("message") //Do Whatever you want
```

PS: just make sure you are checking if the dataSnapshot Exits!

EDIT:

if your first app is the one generating the keys, you can store them in a different node and access that node based on position to get the key and after you make sure you accessed that node just query for the key

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your first sentence *you cannot get them* but that's not really accurate. You can read in the parent node and iterate over the child nodes, which will have keys, or you can query for specific child node(s) which will also have keys. So yes, you can get to them by those methods. If you will notice the two nodes have a user 'vivik' that sent the messages so if you query the parent node for 'vivik' you will get those child nodes and their keys.